# How can I save myself from an island in lava?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I defeated a Muscly Diggle at level 10 and right after that the Blink Curse teleported me onto a small island in the middle of lava. It was in its last turn, so I have no chance of using it to jump back.

It's been a long time since my last manual save, so I wanted to kill myself and continue from the last autosave. [I'm not playing on Hardcore, since the game used to crash on me quite often.] When I tried to do that, the game auto-saved.

My Knightly Leap won't reach and I don't have access to any more Spatial Instability Infusion. **Is there any way to save myself, without having to replay the last hour or two?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too late for that character, but for future readers: if you get stuck like this, you can [start Dredmor in debug mode](http://dredmod.com/wiki/Debug_Mode) and then use the `p` and `P` keys to teleport up and down dungeon levels. Teleport up, then restart Dredmor in normal mode and there you go.